# iPhone data transfer using CFReadStream & CFWriteStream (bonjour)

Tags: ios, ios4, bonjour, cfreadstream

I am able to send data upto 20 KB from one Mac to another using iPhone Simulators successfully.However for data larger than that it is not able to send.Even fragmenting data doesnot work. Help...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit obscure to be answered adequately. Without any of your code, output, or examples, we don't have a lot to go on.

A great tutorial exists, however, for networking between different Mac/iPhone devices, and is available here:

http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/

If you're interested in learning how to properly network two devices, it's a fantastic start. The project provides a lot of great classes that add a thin Objective-C layer on top of the standard C socket functions, and can make your networking headaches go away very quickly.